# Excel vba: highlight the selected text in textbox in color

Tags: excel, vba

I am trying to highlight the selected text in textbox (which is in UserForm) in color. However, I have not been able to do this with the code. When I do this, the entire text in the textbox turns yellow, but I only want to highlight selected areas of the text in yellow.

I guess maybe I need to change `Me.TextBoxSafety.ForeColor = RGB(255, 255, 0)` this part of code a bit but I am not sure. How can I do that? `.SelColor` doesnt work (internet said I can use `.SelColo`r)

```
Private Sub Label10_Click()

    Dim selectedText As String


    If Me.TextBoxSafety.SelLength > 0 Then
        selectedText = Mid(Me.TextBoxSafety.Text, Me.TextBoxSafety.SelStart + 1, Me.TextBoxSafety.SelLength)
        Me.TextBoxSafety.ForeColor = RGB(255, 255, 0)
        Me.TextBoxSafety.SelLength = 0
    End If
End Sub
```

Comment: I don't think it is possible to set individual color for selected text. But you could use `.SelText` to retrieve the text itself --> `selectedText = Me.TextBoxSafety.SelText`

Comment: This is an amazing question. I can actually write a lengthy post on why it is not possible to achieve what you want even using APIs or Sendkeys. The only way possible is so convoluted that I feel repulsive even thinking about it as it comes with lot of restrictions and side effects and involves registry handling. You'd be better off using a Rich TextBox instead of a normal Textbox.

Comment: I noticed that with rich textbox yes. But before I make the effort I just tried if it would work what I want. This is a form that I fill out in UserForm, as soon as I click the button the texts in textbox are saved in access database and a form is created from it and this is sent by mail to target as pdf. Now I tested it, I have changed textbox font color but it comes black to database, so it does not help that I change font color in textbox.

Comment: Unless you know a way I can do it. I'm currently working in OneNote and then I send the page as a PDF by email. I want to automate this and everything has worked so far. I'm just missing the functions in OneNote, which I can then change the font color, size, etc. But of course I can't compare my app with OneNote...